# Possible to Use gradle to save gzip winder Win7?

Tags: docker, gradle, gzip

I have a set up-
local PC with a docker.exe file (no docker installation)
remote server running docker daemon + repo.

I’m using gradle task to save images to the local PC:

```
project.exec{ ExecSpec exe->
{
exe.commandLine “{docker exe path}”
exe.args “save”, “-o”, “{tag}”, “{output path}”
}
```

It works and saves a .tar on the PC.
Now I’m trying to save the image compressed with gz/bz/xz, but no matter how i arrange the args, this doesn’t work.
now if i try to do it via cmd , it works:
“{docker exe path} save {tag} | gzip > {output path}”
is it possible to do this using gradle? can anyone help me please.

using Win 7, docker.exe version 18.09.2, gradle version 5.4.1
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use shell constructs like the redirect operator `>` because Gradle doesn't delegate the command to a shell.

If you like, you can use [bmuschko's docker plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-docker-plugin) instead, as that supports saving images with compression. Here is an example of how to use that (in the Groovy DSL):

```
plugins {
    id "com.bmuschko.docker-remote-api" version "5.0.0"
}

import com.bmuschko.gradle.docker.tasks.image.*

task saveDockerImage(type: DockerSaveImage) {
    destFile = layout.buildDirectory.file("my-docker-image.tgz")
    repository = "my/image"
    tag = "latest"
    useCompression = true
}
```

The advantage to this approach is that it relatively simple to use, and works on both Windows and Unix platforms, and you don't even need to have docker installed locally if you work on a remote repository.

But if you don't want to use a third-party plugin, you will have to save the image it as a tar file (as this is what `docker save` does) and then run another `exec` command that gzips it (or using whatever other compression tool you like to use).

You could also create a bat or bash script that does all this, and then execute that from Gradle. But that is also not as elegant as using a plugin IMHO.